# Excel - find every instance of a name and return the column header of each instance

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

Here's a headscratcher...

I have a huge spreadsheet (Up to GA,397) with a list of groups across the top and all the members of the groups going down from these.

(I also have the data in the alternate orientation)

I have a list of all the unique members and all the groups separately.

What I need is a summary of the data showing a list of the members and every group they belong to (ideally groups listed in separate rows or columns so they can be filtered and searched).

I thought about pivots - but the data is too big for that to be practical and I have a small amount of experience with basic Macros.

Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks,
Bobby

Comment: You could put it in [PowerPivot](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29074) - handles large datasets like a champ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following code:

`Sub test()`

`Dim i As Integer
Dim inputWS As Worksheet, outputWS As Worksheet
Set inputWS = Sheets("input")
Set outputWS = Sheets("output")`

`i = 1`

`For Each cell In inputWS.Range("A2:B374")
    i = i + 1
    outputWS.Cells(i, "A").Value = cell.Value
    outputWS.Cells(i, "B").Value = inputWS.Cells(1, cell.Column).Value
Next`

`End Sub`

depending on the original range which you would need to amend according to your required range would pull all data from it from sheet "input", populate it in column "A" of sheet "output" and also add the headers(values in first row) of each element of original range into column "B" of the "output" sheet. this would give you a more robust list to do a pivot on.
P.S. that is handy of course only if i understood your requirements correctly, which are unfortunately are not as clear as i'd hope

**EDIT**
following from your comment try the following:

```
Sub test()
Dim col As Integer, rw As Integer, counter As Integer
Dim inputWS As Worksheet, outputWS As Worksheet
Set inputWS = Sheets("input")
Set outputWS = Sheets("output")
counter = 0

For rw = 2 To inputWS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

  For col = 2 To inputWS.Cells(rw, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    counter = counter + 1
    outputWS.Cells(counter, 1).Value = inputWS.Cells(rw, col).Value
    outputWS.Cells(counter, 2).Value = inputWS.Cells(rw, 1).Value

  Next
Next

End Sub
```

this will normalise the data on your output sheet putting all members in column A and all groups they were in into column B, creating multiple entries, after that do a pivot on the data putting members as row labels and groups as column labels and do a count on either field in values field. This means that instead showing group names next to each name it will show non blank cells underneath each group header, is that acceptable?

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't very clear. I have a list of groups in column A and all the members across in the row. What I need is a list of all the members in column A and all the groups they belong to in the corresponding row. Is that clearer/easier?